# How to vertically float div up to next one if there is space

Tags: html, css

I got array of posts that are being loaded from api then displayed onto view. So its dynamic content. Height of post vary depending of the content so i need to display them rowless in 2 columns. So width is fixed and height is not. For now it looks like this: [image]

My code looks basically like this, html:

```
<div class="posts-wrapper">
   <div class="post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
   </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.posts-wrapper {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     .post { 
            padding: 7px;
            width: 49%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #c2cfd6;
     }
}
```

What i wanna accomplish is that div 3 to move up to div 1... height of post is not defined, its unknown, so its unknown in which column post should go. It should float by itself, like flowing to the side where it VERTICALLY finds first empty space.

**EDIT:: Maybe better explanation would be.. Next post is going to be placed in column that is smaller in height, with left column having advance if they are even.**

So layout would look something like this: [image]

Tried googling it but i dont even know what to google, what kind of layout is this. Anyways, any help, hits, keywords, is appreciated.

Comment: try to use `float:left`.

Comment: @AndrewLi tried both on post and wrapper, didnt change anything.

Comment: What you are looking for is a solution for **masonry layout**. There's plenty of good material around, but the one you need is kinda tricky, like this one here [link](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/QKwvxJ)

Comment: @luenib i srsly thought its masonry-layout, but its not.. it looks same tho, but it splits array in two columns, and it firstly fills left one, then right one... but i need it to be done alternately.... "EDIT:: Maybe better explanation would be.. Next post is going to be placed in column that is smaller in height, with left column having advance if they are even."

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Edited answer now that I understand you are looking for a layout where you can optimally position various `div` elements of unknown heights without having the columns get too "lopsided". `column-count` will help with this. Updated snippet below.

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.one, .two, .three, .four {
  width: 100%;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.four {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
</div>
```

ORIGINAL:

Several different ways to get a layout like the one you describe. Here is a fairly basic approach using flexbox since it seems like that is the direction you are trying to go (the relevant code is primarily the `.container`, `.left`, and `.right` `div` elements along with the corresponding css). Most of the rest of the css is just to mimic varying content heights to illustrate the effect.

Note that you will have to adjust your template to alternate loading of posts in each of the left and right columns in order to use this approach.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 8px;
  width: 50%;
}

.one, .two, .three, .four {
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.three {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}

.four {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="three">Three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="two">Two</div>
    <div class="four">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea i found similar solutions but thats for the case when u know the height of divs (so u know when its going to go right/left). But in my case, i dont know when it should go right or left. Height is dynamic so there might be 2 divs on right and 6-7 on left.

Comment: @Kerim092 so your issue with a 2 column layout is that you might get too many long posts on one side or the other resulting in a lopsided layout. I see what you are after now... You should edit your question to make that extra clear so you get the help you need. If I get a chance a bit later, I will come back to this.

Comment: Still not it... in your example first column gonna be filled first, then second column.. so post wont be sorted from top down which i need cause i want newest posts to be on top... check edited question.. anyways thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Kerim092 not sure that is possible with pure css solution, but you never know. Guessing that you will need to look at some js masonry stuff to get what you want.